# how can i get a list of azure vm ids in terraform and then read them back one value at a time?

Tags: azure, terraform

I need to get a list of all VM ids in an Azure subscription using Terraform then read them back one by one and feed one id at a time to a module to perform some tasks on it, how can i do this?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the feature multiple instances of the data source to get the list of all the VM ids. See the data source `azurerm_virtual_machine`, it requires the name and the resource group name. So if the VMs in the same group, you just need to create a list variable for all the VM names, then the data block will be like this:

```
variable "vm_names" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    ...
  ]
}

data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  count = length(var.vm_names)
  name  = element(var.vm_names, count.index)
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

output "vm_ids" {
  value = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.*.id
}
```

The output is all the VM ids.